# What's the role of using Map to encapsulate ThreadLocal<Map>?

Tags: java, thread-local

private ThreadLocal<Map<String,Object>> THREAD_LOCAL=new ThreadLocal()<>

1.To explian the difference encapsulate ThreadLocal by myself and use it's ThreadLocalMap.
2.How to select suitable Data Structures to encapsulate in coding?

Answer (score 2):

The `ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap` class is an *internal* class used by the `ThreadLocal` API to represent the thread locals.  It has special properties that make it suitable for that use-case ... and not others.

By contrast

```
ThreadLocal<Map<String, Object>> THREAD_LOCAL = new ThreadLocal()<>;
```

is declaring a thread local that will contain a `Map` value.  `THREAD_LOCAL` is not the map itself.  Rather, it says that any thread have one of those values ... and you access it using the (unhelpfully named) `THREAD_LOCAL` instance.

In the fullness of time, your thread local's (`Map`) values will be held in an instance of `ThreadLocalMap` that is associated with a given `Thread`.  But that is an implementation detail.

> 1.To explian the difference encapsulate ThreadLocal by myself and use it's ThreadLocalMap.

Basically, these are two different things.   The `ThreadLocalMap` holds *all* of the thread-local values for a thread.  Your `Map` will be just one of those values.

But you don't need to understand `ThreadLocalMap`.  It is internal.  And implementation detail.  Not visible to your code.  Code to the `ThreadLocal` API and ignore what happens under the hood.  (Or if you are pathologically curious ... download and read the source code for yourself.)

> 2.How to select suitable Data Structures to encapsulate in coding?

Not sure what you are asking here.  But you shouldn't be directly using or depending on`ThreadLocalMap` in your code.

Comment: How to choose the appropriate data structure to encapsulate ThreadLocal’s local variables

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by encapsulate in this context: what you are trying to achieve.  Or "ThreadLocal’s local variables".  (It doesn't have local variables!)   Please update your question to clarify.